# Can not connect to mysql database [strato]

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection

i bought a web space by strato and now i am trying to connect to the mysql database through php. But every time php say `Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111`

```
Host: rdbms.strato.de
User: Uxxxxx
Database: DBxxxx
```

I also tried to connect width the localhost or 127.0.0.1 host but it doesen't work.

Edit:

The solution was to connect to the url "rdbms.strato.de". As username you need your database user name ("UXXXXX") and as password your database password. After the connection was successfully you need to change your database to your database name ("DBXXXXX").

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why don't you ask your webhost about this problem?

Comment: Because they dont answer before one day :/

Comment: @Nimmi have you heard back from them?

Comment: @dreamlab oh sry i forgot to update the answer.

Comment: @Nimmi is the database connection still working for you? i get the "reading initial communication packet" error, with your proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

Connection posibilities(access) depends on your hosting package. But, actually, remote connections to strato mySQL is not allowed(security reasons).
I have the same trouble with PowerWeb Basic.