# Can't connect to MySQL server (hosted by strato) error: 2013 lost connection to mysql server at 'reading initial communication packet' system error 0

Tags: mysql, ssh, putty, ssh-tunnel, navicat

Hi I am trying to connect to my MySQL DB which is hosted by strato. On their site I can create a DB and I did. I am able to connect via PuTTy like shown [in this link](https://www.strato.com/faq/en_us/article/567/This-is-how-you-can-use-our-MySQL-database.html). And I found the port, hostname etc as you can see [image: on this screenshot] but now I am trying to connect to the database via NaviCat but I keep getting the following error: `2013 lost connection to mysql server at 'reading initial communication packet' system error 0`.

I configured NaviCat like this (as password I filled in the masterpassword strato provided me) [image: general settings]

and this (as password I filled in the masterpassword strato provided me)

[image: this]

Screenshot of the error I am getting: [image: error]

There is also a page on my hosters site with an tutorial on how to connect to their DB using PuTTy: [link to page](https://www.strato.com/faq/en_us/article/567/This-is-how-you-can-use-our-MySQL-database.html)

Maybe you're wondering why I don't contect the host, it takes ages for them to reply...

What am I doing wrong why cant I connect how can I fix it?
If anyone can help me i would rlly appreciate it!

Comment: Strato! :-) They make good systems, don't worry!

Comment: Why `brenda`? Where did you took that from? Use `rdbms.strato.de`. I see you claim that you get the same error. But at least update your question to show that you really tried the right way.

Comment: @peterh I'm sure they do, but what use is an offline cloud database?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl okay I'll change it but why does PuTTy give me the hostname `Brenda`?

Comment: When you connect through putty, and you run the "set" command, do you see any variables related to mysql?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Offline cloud? It seems a contradictional terminology to me. Maybe offline mirror of a cloud db?

Comment: @peterh  I meant it that way, and so does Strato: their DB's are only meant to be used by applications they host.  I'm quite sure they've disabled tunneling in their sshd.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Tunneling over sshd is surely not a solution for a productive remote mysql usage. I think the OP should either use some synchronization with a local mysql, or some http-based (but, at least, stateless) RPC to use the strato mysql. Alternatively, he should use a vpn to make that mysql looking local on his local network.

Comment: @peterh  You take the words out of my mouth (see my comment on my second answer).  But the VPN will need cooperation from Strato.

Answer (score 4):

The manual says the hostname for a database connection should be

```
rdbms.strato.de
```

Answer (score 4):

Or has this never been possible?  I quote [Can not connect to mysql database [strato]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138413/can-not-connect-to-mysql-database-strato):

> Connection posibilities(access) depends on your hosting package. But,
>   actually, remote connections to strato mySQL is not allowed(security
>   reasons). I have the same trouble with PowerWeb Basic.

The access is probably meant for applications you host with them, not running elsewhere (eg. at home).

If you want to work locally, perhaps they allow you to take a dump of your database that you can install locally?   Do they have PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: OP is not really connecting remotely. OP is connecting via SSH tunnel.

Comment: I think Strato has disabled ssh tunneling.

Comment: They have PHPMyAdmin. But I am trying to connect over SSH so it doesn't matter that they block rote connections, right? Maybe it's good to mention the purpose of the DB. I am creating an application that uses an login system which I wanna link to the DB. So the I need to be able to log in remotely to the DB.

Comment: They have a tutorial on there site on how to do it with PuTTY and that works so I don't think they're blocking SSH?

Comment: Dat zal niet gaan, Levi.  Not if Strato blocks tunneling.

Comment: But if they blocked tunneling how come that I am able to connect to the MySQL server using PuTTY?

Comment: That's not tunneling!  The sshd has given you access to a shell.  I don't know if it is a standard shell.  The mysql client you start connects to a DB without specifying which port, although the DB is not listening on 3306.  Why would you need to access remotely via mysql client?  Can't you provide the necessary functionalities through your application?  Some kind of management API you write yourself?  See comment by @peterh.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Indeed, it's possible. So maybe you should be more explicit about that in the answer.

Comment: Sorry @MartinPrikryl , about what should I be more explicit?

Comment: @LeviVerkerk, will your application be hosted by Strato?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille no it will be an exe which the user will be able to run locally on his/her computer

Comment: OK, but then you will need a small application with Strato that answers the exe's call.  You'll need some safety measures so that not anyone can make these calls.